# Rails Seed Data from file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to create some seed data and got this code from Railcasts. I've modified it slightly but doesn't seem to be working when i run **bundle exec rake db:seed** from the terminal. I get the following error in the terminal...

```
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
```

Below is my code in the seeds.rb file to populate the table. Is there a silly mistake in there somewhere?

```
require 'open-uri'

International.delete.all
open("international.txt") do |countries|
  countries.read.each_line do |data|
    code, country, currency = data.chomp.split("|")
    International.create!(:code => code, :country => country, :currency => currency)
  end
end
```

and my text file (stored in the same directory as the seeds.rb file is...

```
AU|Australia|AUD
CA|Canada|CAD
GB|United Kingdom|GBP
US|United States|USD
```

Comment: does it tell you what method you have the wrong number of arguments for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass an id to [delete](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/delete/class).

I assume you want to `delete_all`

```
International.delete_all
```